# question about system root and application installation

Tags: 20.04, permissions, root

Hi everyone I'm new to ubuntu and trying to install a finance application on it. On the installation guide it tells me that the application should not run on system root. Right now I don't really understand about connection between installation and user on ubuntu.

1. If I install an application is it installed on system root (administrator on windows) and can be access to all?
2. second question is about "not running it on root system". If question no 1 is true and I should not run it on root system then I just need to create a new user and give permission to the application and run it from that user, is this correct?

Comment: Without knowing what application you're referring to, it'll be hard to help you.  Applications installed on Windows have no impact on Ubuntu and vice versa, so I'm not entirely sure what your question really is.

Comment: My question isn't about the application. I'm asking about how the application works on ubuntu and how it is relate with root or non-root user.

Comment: Installing an application and running an application are different things. You may need _root_-privileges to install. That doesn't mean it wouldn't be accessable to other users. When you run the application you should run it with a user who has sufficient  privileges to run it. You should not run it as a _root_ since _root_ has unlimited access to everything on your computer. Running as _root_ adds a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Applications are started by executable files, i.e., binary executable or scripts that have the executable bit set. Who can start the executable is determined by the permissions set on the file.

Some applications are contained in a single stand alone . You can just execute the executable wherever it resides on the file system, and the program will run successfully.

Other applications are more complex. In order to successfully run, libraries and other files they need need to be installed in specific locations. When you use the Ubuntu software center or `apt` on the command line, this is automatically performed through installation scripts contained in the `.deb` installation file.

By default *no* applications run as system root. Whether the application is a system wide installed application, or a single executable in your home folder, when you start it up, it will *not* run as system root. It will run as a process of the user who launched it. The administrator needs to specifically set it up if an application must run as root.

Formerly, some graphical applications were run as root. That is still the case with for example "Synaptic Package Manager". However, current trend is to *never* run a graphical application as root, and rather spawn processes as root only for specific actions. The application "Disks" is an example of this more modern approach. Only when you are about to do something that needs root permissions will the application ask your password, and only then launch the processes needed to carry out the task, e.g., formatting a drive.

> If I install an application is it installed on system root (administrator on windows) and can be access to all?

If the system administrator decides so, then yes. In other words, this is not a general rule. However, most commonly, applications are there to be used by users. So the administrator (system root) installs them in system folders in a way that they can be started by all users.

> second question is about "not running it on root system". If question no 1 is true and I should not run it on root system then I just need to create a new user and give permission to the application and run it from that user, is this correct?

If you wish to restrict applications to specific users only, then indeed you can set that up. You do *not* need creating a new user. You rather need to configure the application this way that it can only be run by that specific user. One way is to install that application in a directory under the home folder of that particular user, so it will not be visible nor accessible - depending on the permissions - by other users.

Comment: so far I understand your explanation, and thanks for that! Learn a lot. One more question though, when we create our user we have an access as administrator and root. Does "don't run the application as root" also mean as my user?